# How to select 2nd and 3rd row for each group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to select 2nd and 3rd entry for each group in a dataframe. I have been trying but getting an error.

Sample Data:

```
USER.ID   restaurant
3            aaaa
3            ababa
3            asddw
4            bbbb
4            wedwe
2            ewedw
1            qwqw
1            dwqd
1            dqed
1            ewewq
```

Desired output:

```
USER.ID    2nd_restaurant   3rd_restaurant
3            ababa             asddw
3            ababa             asddw
3            ababa             asddw
4            wedwe             NA
4            wedwe             NA
2            NA                NA
1            dwqd              dqed
1            dwqd              dqed
1            dwqd              dqed
1            dwqd              dqed
```

I tried using dplyr, but I guess due to huge size of data, it is taking a long time to compute. Is there a way to compute it more efficiently?

My code:

```
data1 <- data %>%
arrange(USER.ID) %>%
group_by(USER.ID) %>%
mutate(second_restaurant = data[2,11]) %>%
mutate(third_restaurant = data[3,11])
```

11 is the column number of restaurant in original data set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy the restaurant column first, and then use `mutate` to extract the relevant values:

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(restaurant2 = restaurant) %>%
  group_by(USER.ID) %>%
  mutate(restaurant = restaurant[2], restaurant2 = restaurant2[3])
# Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
# Groups: USER.ID
# 
#    USER.ID restaurant restaurant2
# 1        3      ababa       asddw
# 2        3      ababa       asddw
# 3        3      ababa       asddw
# 4        4      wedwe          NA
# 5        4      wedwe          NA
# 6        2         NA          NA
# 7        1       dwqd        dqed
# 8        1       dwqd        dqed
# 9        1       dwqd        dqed
# 10       1       dwqd        dqed
```

Or, better yet (courtesy @StevenBeaupré):

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(USER.ID) %>% 
  transmute(restaurant2 = nth(restaurant, 2), 
            restaurant3 = nth(restaurant, 3))
```

---

Or, if you prefer "data.table", to paraphrase @DavidArenburg, you can try:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, `:=`(restaurant_2 = restaurant[2L], 
                           restaurant_3 = restaurant[3L]), by = USER.ID][]
```

---

Or, you can even use base R:

```
mydf[c("restaurant_2", "restaurant_3")] <- with(mydf, lapply(c(2, 3), function(x) {
  ave(restaurant, USER.ID, FUN = function(y) y[x])
}))
```

Comment: I was going to post almost the same with `data.table`, so I'll put it here ```library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, `:=`(restaurant_2 = restaurant[2L], restaurant_3 = restaurant[3L]), by = USER.ID]```

Comment: Or without recopying the first column using `transmute()` and `nth()`:  `df %>% group_by(USER.ID) %>% transmute(restaurant2 = nth(restaurant, 2), restaurant3 = nth(restaurant, 3))`

Comment: @people! This is SO. I don't own these answers, so feel free to use the edit button :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple order in the row names of your data frame, using the modulo operator might also be a way to go (the following selects each 2nd row, change 2 to n to select each nth row):

```
mydf %>% filter(as.numeric(row.names(.)) %% 2 == 0)
```